Where would I clear passport control on a connecting intra-Schengen flight?
I am from a country that requires a visa to enter the Schengen Area. I have obtained my visa for an upcoming trip, where the first point of entry, as well as the embassy that issued the visa, and my primary destination are all Greece. However, on the first day of my trip I have to go to Spain. There is a connecting flight, my city->Greece->Spain, which is way cheaper than buying the flights individually, but I am afraid if I don't buy the flights individually, it may contradict the information on my visa.
Where will I get my passport stamped? I assume it is the first entry point in the Schengen Area, which in this case is Greece. Does it change from country to country? Will I run into issues at passport control if my primary destination is Greece, but I am transiting to Spain?
Thanks!

"Does it change from country to country?": There can be a "non-systematic" document check on arrival, but everyone on an internal flight is inside the Schengen area.  There's no way certain countries could send internal passengers to an external border checkpoint.  When you arrive on an external flight, you have to be formally admitted to the Schengen area before you can get to the boarding gate for an internal flight, not after disembarking.


My question is, where will I get my passport stamped?

In Greece, at your port of entry

Will I run into issues at passport control if my primary destination is Greece, but I am transiting to Spain?

As long as you haven't misrepresented your plans (like wanting to go to Spain and not Greece) during your visa application, you will have no issues.

but I am afraid if I don't buy the flights individually, it may contradict the information on my Visa.

No need to overthink this.
